# Call an array value inside Class

Tags: php, arrays, class, function, object

I want to create a simple command when an array is called. In this case it would be the ON button inside a remote control. (Illustrative concept). But is not working (syntax error).

This is my piece of code:

```
    <?php
class remoteControl{

    public $operate = array("ON", "OFF", "UP","DOWN");



    public function pressButton($operate("0")){
    echo "You have pressed ". $this->operate;
    }
}

$control_01 = new remoteControl();

echo $control_01-> pressButton();

?>
```

Any help would be very greatful :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have few syntax errors suggesting that you should read [PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/) about basics.

Your code (formatted):

```php
<?php 
class remoteControl {
    public $operate = array("ON", "OFF", "UP","DOWN"); // 1) 

    public function pressButton($operate("0")) {  // 2), 3), 4)
        echo "You have pressed ". $this->operate; // 5)
    }
}

$control_01 = new remoteControl();                
echo $control_01-> pressButton();

?>
```

1) you should make this variable private if used only inside class methods

2) using arrays: $operate[0] - [read more](http://pl.php.net/manual/en/book.array.php)

3) don't use string as index ("0") - it will work, but its unnecessary type casting

4) finally, this line should be something like this:

```php
public function pressButton($operate = 0) {
```

which means that if you don't explicitly provide an argument it will have value 0 - [read more about function arguments](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php)

5) because of 4) it should be:

```php
echo "You have pressed ". $this->operate[$operate];
```

EDIT: Whole code:

```php
<?php
class remoteControl {
    private $operate = array("ON", "OFF", "UP", "DOWN");

    public function pressButton($operate = 0) {
        echo "You have pressed ". $this->operate[$operate];
    }
}

$control_01 = new remoteControl();                
echo $control_01->pressButton();

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

did not clearly get what you intent to do with your code ,
you seem to pass one element of operate array to your function .
hope this code helps : http://codepad.org/CYVT7hI5

```
 <?php
class remoteControl{

    public $operate = array("ON", "OFF", "UP","DOWN");



    public function pressButton($index){
    echo "You have pressed ". $this->operate[$index];
    }
}

$control_01 = new remoteControl();

echo $control_01->pressButton(1);

?>
```